# I can't call a function via TouchableOpacity's onPress()

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

I am somewhat at a loss as to why I keep getting `TypeError: Chat.onCameraClick is not a function. (In 'Chat.onCameraClick()', 'Chat.onCameraClick' is undefined)`.

I have the following:

```
export default class Chat extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: 'Chat',
    headerTintColor: colors.HEADERTINT,
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: colors.HEADER,
    },
    headerLeft: () => (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}>
        <Icon
          name="menu"
          size={24}
          style={{ color: colors.BLACK, marginLeft: 10 }}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
    headerRight: () => (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onCameraClick()}>
        <Icon
          name="camera"
          type='font-awesome'
          size={24}
          style={{ color: colors.BLACK, marginRight: 10 }}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
  });
```

Further down, I just have the camera method:

```
  onCameraClick = () => {
    console.log("Pic!");
  }
```

I looked at posts like [RN TouchableOpacity onPress dosn't call function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54945373/rn-touchableopacity-onpress-dosnt-call-function) and the touchableopacity docs here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity but I am unsure as to why this would be "undefined" I have also tried to just call `onPress={this.onCameraClick}` but basically the same happens.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I tried that. No error but nothing happens.

Comment: O shoot  this should work, sorry.... <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onCameraClick}>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this wasn't working was because I'm calling a function from within my class from the navigation and that works separately. In order to get it to work, I had to set the param and then call it above.

Adding to my `componentDidMount()`:

```
this.props.navigation.setParams({ onCameraClick: this.onCameraClick });
```

And then changing the navigation to:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={navigation.getParam('onCameraClick')}>
```

Answer (score 0):

i see your code i have made a little modification in it. and it is working now.

```
headerRight: () => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onCameraClick}> // <<--- here
    <Icon
  name="camera"
  type='font-awesome'
  size={24}
  style={{ color: colors.BLACK, marginRight: 10 }}
/>
  </TouchableOpacity>
),
```

where you called your function just remove the round brackets and just make one arrow function.